# How use a theme or template in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use ionic material theme in a app trying to build using ionic framework. I installed ionic-material and robotidraft using bower. added the scripts also.. but in next step they asked to inject these into the app.. 
how to Inject Ionic & Ionic Material into Ionic App?
where should I add this?

```
var app = angular.module('YOUR_APP_NAME', ['ionic', 'ionic-material']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ionic material with ionic as below ,

```
   angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionic-material'])
```

Make sure you have refered the libraries

```
   <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
   <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:400,500,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/dist/ionic.material.min.js"></script>
   <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/dist/ionic.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**DEMO**

```js
/*global angular*/

angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionic-material'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('eventmenu', {
      url: '/event',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/event-menu.html'
    })
    .state('eventmenu.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.checkin', {
      url: '/check-in',
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: 'templates/check-in.html',
          controller: 'CheckinCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('eventmenu.attendees', {
      url: '/attendees',
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: 'templates/attendees.html',
          controller: 'AttendeesCtrl'
        }
      }
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/event/home');
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $timeout) {

  $timeout(function(){
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
      ionicMaterialMotion.ripple();
  },0);


  $scope.attendees = [
    { firstname: 'Nicolas', lastname: 'Cage' },
    { firstname: 'Jean-Claude', lastname: 'Van Damme' },
    { firstname: 'Keanu', lastname: 'Reeves' },
    { firstname: 'Steven', lastname: 'Seagal' }
  ];

  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
})

.controller('CheckinCtrl', function($scope, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion, $timeout) {

  $timeout(function(){
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
      ionicMaterialMotion.ripple();
  },0);


  $scope.showForm = true;

  $scope.shirtSizes = [
    { text: 'Large', value: 'L' },
    { text: 'Medium', value: 'M' },
    { text: 'Small', value: 'S' }
  ];

  $scope.attendee = {};
  $scope.submit = function() {
    if(!$scope.attendee.firstname) {
      /*jshint ignore:start*/
      alert('Info required');
      /*jshint ignore:end*/
      return;
    }
    $scope.showForm = false;
    $scope.attendees.push($scope.attendee);
  };

})

.controller('AttendeesCtrl', function($scope, ionicMaterialInk, ionicMaterialMotion, $timeout) {

  $timeout(function(){
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
      ionicMaterialMotion.ripple();
  },0);


  $scope.activity = [];
  $scope.arrivedChange = function(attendee) {
    var msg = attendee.firstname + ' ' + attendee.lastname;
    msg += (!attendee.arrived ? ' has arrived, ' : ' just left, ');
    msg += new Date().getMilliseconds();
    $scope.activity.push(msg);
    if($scope.activity.length > 3) {
      $scope.activity.splice(0, 1);
    }
  };

});
/*endglobal angular*/
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>INSERT YOUR PROBLEM NAME HERE</title>

      <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:400,500,700,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/dist/ionic.material.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zachsoft/Ionic-Material/master/dist/ionic.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

    <script id="templates/event-menu.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">

        <ion-side-menu-content>
          <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
              <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
              </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
          </ion-nav-bar>

          <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-side-menu-content>

        <ion-side-menu side="left">
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
            <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <ion-content>
            <ul class="list animate-rip">
              <!-- Note each link has the 'menu-close' attribute so the menu auto closes when clicking on one of these links -->
              <a href="#/event/check-in" class="item" menu-close>Check-in</a>
              <a href="#/event/attendees" class="item" menu-close>Attendees</a>
            </ul>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>

      </ion-side-menus>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Welcome" ng-cont>
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>Swipe to the right to reveal the left menu.</p>
          <p>(On desktop click and drag from left to right)</p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/check-in.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Event Check-in">
        <ion-content>
          <form class="list animate-ripple" ng-show="showForm">
            <div class="item item-divider">
              Attendee Info
            </div>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="attendee.firstname">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="attendee.lastname">
            </label>
            <div class="item item-divider">
              Shirt Size
            </div>
            <ion-radio ng-repeat="shirtSize in shirtSizes"
                       ng-value="shirtSize.value"
                       ng-model="attendee.shirtSize">
              {{ shirtSize.text }}
            </ion-radio>
            <div class="item item-divider">
              Lunch
            </div>
            <ion-toggle ng-model="attendee.vegetarian">
              Vegetarian
            </ion-toggle>
            <div class="padding">
              <button class="button button-block" ng-click="submit()">Checkin</button>
            </div>
          </form>

          <div ng-hide="showForm">
            <pre ng-bind="attendee | json"></pre>
            <a href="#/event/attendees">View attendees</a>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/attendees.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Event Attendees">
        <ion-content>
          <div class="list animate-rip">
            <ion-toggle ng-repeat="attendee in attendees | orderBy:'firstname' | orderBy:'lastname'"
                        ng-model="attendee.arrived"
                        ng-change="arrivedChange(attendee)">
              {{ attendee.firstname }}
              {{ attendee.lastname }}
            </ion-toggle>
            <div class="item item-divider">
              Activity
            </div>
            <div class="item" ng-repeat="msg in activity">
              {{ msg }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```